# htaccess 301 regular expression

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just moved blogging platforms from a custom-made one into WordPress and it looks like a couple of the permalink structures need a 301 redirect. How is this done using regular expressions in regex?

Old: www.domain.com/blog/tag/tag-name.html
New: www.domain.com/blog/tag/tag-name/

Old: www.domain.com/blog/2016/01/01/post-name-here.html
New: www.domain.com/blog/2016/01/01/post-name-here/

While I can do this in the existing .htaccess file, I think this would be impractical as I have a bunch of existing blog posts and categories/tags.

```
Redirect /blog/2016/01/01/post-name-here.html http://www.domain.com/blog/2016/01/01/post-name-here/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(tag/)?(.+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/$1$2
```

This will redirect :

- http://www.example.com/blog/tag/foo.html

to

- http://www.example.com/blog/tag/foo

or

- http://www.example.com/blog/foo.html

to

- http://www.example.com/blog/foo

Comment: I think the extra trailing slash is required here; OP seems to have been specific about it. :)